# session.id changes and socket.io doesn't match

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, webpack-dev-server, express-session

I'm running **webpack-dev-server** on localhost:8000 for my app and **express+socket.io** on port 3000 for my api. I've proxied requests to socket.io in *webpack.config.js* as such:

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '/socket.io': {
            target: 'http://localhost:3000',
            ws: true
        }
    }
}
```

However, not only do the session ids in express and socket.io don't match, the session id in express changes every request:

**Server:**

```
let app = require('express')();
let session = require('express-session')({
    secret: 'panopticon',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
});
let server = require('http').createServer(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(server);

//session middleware
app.use(session);
io.use(require('express-socket.io-session')(session, {
    autoSave: true
}));

let i=0;

app.get('/socket.io', (req, res) => {
    console.log(i++, req.session.id);
    //0 'ShgnU91kCZzC7xHP9B57ZtsCbwi3XjdB'
    //1 'qLsYYpRZXpyoUrcKzF6K7uoAIKtE9oCh'

    res.send();
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log(socket.handshake.session.id);
    //MRUYZMVstMh6ssNrq9LP-Z4vTaT5SZcs
});
```

**Client:**

```
//connect to socket
let socket = io();
//make two requests to /socket.io
fetch('socket.io').then(() => fetch('socket.io'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I got this to work was to do an AJAX request first to `localhost:3000`:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000', {
    credentials: 'include'
});
```

With the following handler on the response:

```
app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1441d3dd846d1a9be34868d575892f93)

Comment: Hi, I think i have a similar problem. Would you be so kind as to post your code on git?

Comment: @Freddie added Gist to answer